# Running Linux GUI/GTK app over SSH (JSch) on remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, gtk, jsch

I am trying to run a GUI application which triggers other GUI app from Windows localhost to SUSE Enterprise Sever 12 edition.

I want to trigger the app using JSch and let it run on the remote machine i.e. SuSe , and do not want to forward it to Windows.

When triggered using normal `.sh` file, the application gives error

> unable to initialize gtk+, is display set properly?

How can I run the application on remote machine, doesn't matter in background or foreground!

Comment: When I was connecting from linux to other linux machine, I called `ssh -X`. Try reading [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can (or not easily). If the app is implemented in a way that needs "display", you cannot run it without one. Note that when you execute an application over SSH (i.e. launched by SSH deamon), it does not know about a physical display (if any at all) connected to the remote machine (the server).

There can be a way to run the application so that it does not require a "display", but that we cannot help you with, as we do not know the application.

Though in general, *nix applications tend to require a "display", when they are run in a session that has TTY. Make sure that you execute the application using an "exec" channel (not "shell") and do not call [`setPty` method](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html#setPty-boolean-).

But if the application is a true GUI application, even this won't help.

---

*Of course, you can somehow emulate the display, but that's beyond my knowledge. For that you would have to ask a different question, with different tags (it's not about [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh)/[jsch](/questions/tagged/jsch), but rather about [tty](/questions/tagged/tty)/[pty](/questions/tagged/pty)/[gtk](/questions/tagged/gtk)).*

Comment: The application is a true GUI application, and it simulates behavior of a modem.
Somehow, I am able to do same thing in Windows-Windows setup, where I trigger the app from one machine and it runs on session 0 on other machine in background.
Is there any thing like "session 0 isolation" in *nix systems?

Comment: I believe there's a huge difference in this respect between Windows and Linux. In Windows, the GUI is a part of a system/kernel (so Windows can pretend to an application, that there's "display", even if there's no really). While in Linux, GUI is not part of a kernel. System  nor SSH deamon is not aware of it. So they cannot help an application with simulating it.

Comment: Actually *"session 0 isolation"* is natural in Linux. - While it was added to Windows only later. That's one of the reason why Windows have to deal with (allow) running GUI application in *"session 0"* not to break compatibility with existing services that required GUI. - On the contrary *nix services (deamons) could never use GUI, so there's no need to support running GUI applications in the background.